# How can i modify the program to return false if the value is not present in an Array

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am using recursion to find an element in an array

```
def recur_search(arr,n,x): #n is the starting index and x is the target value
    if (arr[n] == x):
        return n
    else:
        return recur_search(arr,n+1,x)

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

print(recur_search(arr,0,5))
```

This program only works if i have the element present in the array. If the element is not present the program is throwing IndexErrors. Is there a graceful way to tackle the problem

```
type here
```

I was thinking of checking the presence of element using iteration first but that beats the purpose of recursion. Is there a way to use recursion to find the element if it's present and if its not

Comment: If arr[n:] is empty, you don't need to make a recursive call.

Comment: What is the *problem "type here"*?

Comment: Why are you using recursion for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really insist on using recursion for this then:

```
def recur_search(arr, x):
    def _search(arr, n, x):
        if n < len(arr):
            if arr[n] == x:
                return n
            return _search(arr, n+1, x)
    return _search(arr, 0, x)


arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

print(recur_search(arr, 5))
```

**Output:**

```
4
```